# Run Rails app in different enviroment on Appfog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, appfog

I'd like to run my RoR app on Appfog in the "staging" environment rather than the default "production" environment.

I tried to add an environment variable RAILS_ENV=staging, and restarted the app. However, I got this error:

```
rake aborted!
database configuration does not specify adapter
```

Does anyone try to do this on Appfog ?

Comment: Did you configured "staging" in database.yml?

Comment: Not yet. I will try it. Thanks for your suggestion. I wonder why Appfog auto-configure for production mode, but it doesn't do that for others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating new Environment:

Assuming you want create the hudson environment.

Create a new environment file in config/environments/hudson.rb.

You can start by cloning an existing one, for instance config/environments/test.rb. Add a new configuration block in config/database.yml for your environment. That's all.

Now you can start the server

ruby script/server -e hudson

Run the console

ruby script/server hudson

And so on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After a while to discovery the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable and manually config the database.yml, it works! I think it's annoying because I have to manually do these stuff again whenever the DB service changed, or deploy to a new app. I tried [another approach](https://github.com/appfog/af-ruby-rails/issues/1#issuecomment-6591683), but it can't work. It always raise the error "syntax error, unexpected keyword_rescue"